# Teams Bot Authenticate with Teams Current User

Tags: node.js, authentication, notifications, botframework

I am working on teams bot in node js i need to authenticate the user who invoke the message and get their access token to access the web api which use the same AAD can any one help me in this.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Microsoft Graph Azure AD](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/azuread-identity-access-management-concept-overview) API should help you with managing Azure AD login and tokens.

You can also take a look at [Authentication in bots](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/how-to/authentication/auth-flow-bot) for an overview of how auth works in the Bot Framework as well as related docs on setting up SSO.